# Find Storage For Web Job Details

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Web jobs within app service plans have logging details for the specific web jobs.  Where is this data stored in Azure?  Another way of asking this is how to identify the storage account for an app service plan - it doesn't appear to be under `Overview` or `Properties`.

Answer (score 0):

The WebJob logs sit in the following folder:

- For **Continuous** Webjobs: `D:\home\data\jobs\continuous\jobname`
- For **Triggered** Webjobs: `D:\home\data\jobs\triggered\jobname`

To answer the second part, you need to know that in Azure App Services, the **`D:\Home`** points to storage and this is not accessible to external world. So there is no way for one to identify the storage account for an app service plan.

Read more about Azure App Service architecture here: [Inside the Azure App Service Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt793270.aspx)

Also see [this](http://Inside%20the%20Azure%20App%20Service%20Architecture)